Geometry node pattern Diamond
I need some advice here on how to simply re-create the picture bellow in geometry node.

1/ choosing the size and number of the diamond
2/ choosing the spacing gradually
3/ adding some thickness and bevel
How would you proceed to apply this to any surfaces ?
Many thanks

What have you tried? Were are you stuck? If you want to apply it to any surfaces I would use the image as displacement map. If you want to create the geometry with GN I would start with a 45° grid and instance diamonds on the points. Then scale them along the Y-axis.

Or you can start with a plane and turn it into a rectangle with half the height. Then add a Subdivision Surface modifier and a Decimate modifier. They will create the diamond 45° grid. Then instance the diamonds on it with Geometry Nodes. I used scaled cubes in this example: https://i.sstatic.net/UDHA81XE.jpg (it's not perfect, but it gives you an idea)



I would approach this by the following way:
Use grid node with which you can control the size and number of your instanced object. Connect it to mesh to points node to distribute points on which the instances will be. From its drop down menu -> edges (that will grant the diagonal distribution of the points). That goes into Instances on points in the points socket.
Since i'm not aware of a way to bevel a shape inside Geonodes i have used simple plane which i scaled along one axis in edit mode (the axis depend entirely from you) since after you can rotate it as much as you wish -> after this little extrusion and bevel modifier.
With object info node you can bring your shape into the existing Geonode tree by drag and drop it from the Scene collection panel or by adding it manually with ctr+A. Then Object info node is connected to a transform node in which you can modify the scale of your instances. all this go in to Instances on point in the instance socket.
For the fall off from small to big i have used proximity node controlled by an empty object placed in the Scale socket of the instances on points node for further tweaking you can add map range or color ramp between Proximity and instance on points. I hope this helps!

Here is one approach where a single mesh line is instanced on itself two times:


